# Wildfly hot deploy of Static content (Javascripts, HTML, CSS) without restarting the server in Spring STS

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, wildfly, incremental-build

I'm using Wildfly 9.0.0.Alpha1 with Spring STS 3.6.3 and JBoss Tools, i don't find the way for update my changes to static content inside my server without the need of use incremental deploy (I enabled exploded deployment in the wildfly server), so when i do a little change to my resources, I have to refresh the project in eclipse STS so then it makes an incremental deployment, this takes about 15 - 30 seconds which is annoying and a waste of time

There is a way for update a static content in a exploded war without incremental deploy?

Comment: incremental deploy *is* what allows to updated content without restarting the server thus I do not understand the question.

Why it takes 15-30 seconds I do not understand since we have the default set to ~2 seconds refresh.

Comment: so i'm confusing it, what i tried to said is when i do a change to, for example, in a javascript file and then i go to my eclipse project and i press F5 for update it in my  IDE, wildfly detects the change (JBoss tools) over my project and proceeds to restart the server automatically (what i thing is incremental deployment). I do the same process using Glassfish 4.1 and it works, i check the option in server options in both cases: "Automatically publish after a resource change"

Comment: JBoss Tools should by default not restart the server unless you say yes to it. And we should only be suggesting restart if you changed .class files - and again it should only be an option. javascript, css, html etc. should just be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your subsystem entry for undertow, adding a location and file for a path within standalone/tmp. And then you can add symbolic links to that path at runtime every time you want to share additional static content. You can use Files.createSymbolicLink(...) in Java. Just be careful that the attributes of your symbolic links let them be deleted without deleting the targets. Also, make a start script that recreates your subdirectory in tmp as needed before wildly starts. If you have an undertow location that points to a folder that doesn't exist, the location (context, like /static) will not be created. Once created, undertow will serve up any subfolder or file you add to it once location is created at startup. Make sure you add directory-browsing="false" attribute to the file element for the folder if you don't want people to be able to list contents of folder.